# ajaxStart() doesn't trigger when ajaxComplete() is defined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trigger a loader icon when ajax request is sent. It works perfectly fine when the ajaxStart() alone is defined. But doesn't work when ajaxComplete() is defined. This is something weird. I have done this many time but not sure what's going wrong here.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $(document).ajaxStart(function(){console.log('into loader');

    $('section,nav').css({'opacity' : '0.5'});
    $(".loader").css("display", "block");
 });
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){console.log('out from loader');
    //$('section,nav').css({'opacity' : '1'});
    //$(".loader").css("display", "none");
 });
});
```

The above code works fine but below one doesn't work. I don't see what is causing the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).ajaxStart(function(){console.log('into loader');

        $('section,nav').css({'opacity' : '0.5'});
        $(".loader").css("display", "block");
    });
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){console.log('out from loader');
        $('section,nav').css({'opacity' : '1'});
        $(".loader").css("display", "none");
    });
});
```

Comment: What gives to you console?

Comment: console perfectly prints what is logged.

Comment: It means ajaxStart works correctly you should focus on your css code it couldn't work what you expect

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with the css in the code. The problem is `ajaxComplete()` and `ajaxStart()` if the `async` in the ajax call is set to `false`.